# I need help rewording for my application

Tags: interviewing

I need to fill out an application for a job, and it needs to be clear I have these traits: dependable, punctual and fast learner.

I can simply use the words themselves, but is there a better way to indicate my qualifications?

Answer (score 1):

Recommend not using them at all, as they are throwaway words that many candidates use because they sound good and are difficult to verify, so overusing these words will make many hiring managers wonder if you are lying to them.

Recommend writing in a manner that is grammar and spelling error free, easy to understand, and lays out your technical skills.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the words at all.  Explain how in previous jobs you were dependable, punctual, and a fast learner.

> At MegaCorp, I was dropped in the middle of a large project with very little training, but I immediately started figuring things out.  My team lead was pleased with how happy I was learning, and after six months, people were coming to me for guidance on the project.  I was always available, and if I didn't have the answer, I knew how to find it.  The project was successful, and the CEO thanked me for my part in it.

You'd have to change the narrative to match what you've done, but that shows fast learning and dependability.  Figure out what shows those traits, and speak in concrete terms of them.

Comment: Well written and gives a verification path. +1